# I would like to send emails to every email address in my database using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, email

I would like to be able to send emails to everyone in my mysql database. As of now the code below will only send an email to the first row in my mysql table. The goal is to send one email to all the users in my database.

```
<?php
//Connect To Database
include "../connection_string.php";

mysql_connect($host,$username, $password) or die ("<html><script language='JavaScript'>alert('Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.'),history.go(-1)</script></html>");
mysql_select_db($db_name);

$result = mysql_query("select property_notifications.email, crm.city, crm.state, crm.primary_fname, crm.primary_lname, crm.bedrooms, crm.baths, crm.assignee, userinfo.fname, userinfo.lname, userinfo.company, userinfo.homecontact, userinfo.clientid from inmobilmex_connect.property_notifications join inmobilmex_connect.crm on property_notifications.email=crm.primary_email join inmobilmex_connect.userinfo where property_notifications.sender=userinfo.clientid");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$recipients=$row['email'];
$prospect_city=$row['city'];
$prospect_state=$row['state'];
$prospect_fname=$row['primary_fname'];
$prospect_lname=$row['primary_lname'];
$bedrooms=$row['bedrooms'];
$baths=$row['baths'];
$realtor_assignee=$row['assignee'];
$fname=$row['fname'];
$lname=$row['lname'];
$company=$row['company'];
$homecontact=$row['homecontact'];
$clientid=$row['clientid'];

//sends email via CRON Jobs
$to = $recipients;
$headers .= 'From: INMOBILMEX <inmobilmex@inmobilmex.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: inmobilmex@inmobilmex.com'. "\r\n";
$subject = "INMOBILMEX - Nuevas propiedades disponibles en $prospect_city $prospect_state";
$body = "Hola $prospect_fname $prospect_lname,\n \nA continuacion aparece un enlace sobre las busquedas de propiedades que coinciden con su peticion. \n\n http://www.inmobilmex.com/home_search_results.php?optionsRadios=option1&state=&city=$prospect_city&bedrooms=$bedrooms&baths=$baths \n\nFavor de comunicarse conmigo si le interesa alguna propiedad.\n\nQuedo de usted,\n$fname $lname\n$company\n$homecontact\n$cellcontact\n$clientid";

mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Any Help is appreciated!

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Hello Jay, Ill start looking into using PDO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$recipients=$row['email'];
$prospect_city=$row['city'];
$prospect_state=$row['state'];
$prospect_fname=$row['primary_fname'];
$prospect_lname=$row['primary_lname'];
$bedrooms=$row['bedrooms'];
$baths=$row['baths'];
$realtor_assignee=$row['assignee'];
$fname=$row['fname'];
$lname=$row['lname'];
$company=$row['company'];
$homecontact=$row['homecontact'];
$clientid=$row['clientid'];
```

put these lines inside the while loop

Comment: Hi Karl! Thanks for the response.. Unfortunately after making the change an email is still only sent to the email address on the first row of the table... any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked your sql query? Does it give you the desired rows? Also be careful because some free web hosting services don't allow the user to send a lot of emails in a short period of time. Other than that i don't see any errors.

Comment: I'll Check! Thank you for the help!